# How do you define operator when creating new ERC-777?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

My understanding is that you can define an operator when instantiating a custom ERC-777, that can make transfers without needing to be approved by the senders using the `operatorSend` function. However, can't seem to get the address of the contract that deploys the token into the inherited constructor. I tried pushing the address into the array in the body of the constructor, but that doesn't seem to take.

```
contract MainToken is ERC777 {
    address[] ops=;
  constructor ()  ERC777("MYTOKEN", "MTK",ops) {
      ops.push(msg.sender);
    }
...
}
```

If I try putting it directly into the constructor like so `ERC777("MYTOKEN", "MTK",[msg.sender])`, I get

> Invalid type for argument in modifier invocation. Invalid implicit
> conversion from address[1] memory to address[] memory requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solidity currently doesn't allow defining a dynamic-size array in one expression. *Note: `[msg.sender]` from your example is a fixed-size array definition.*

Also, your approach with defining the `ops` property doesn't work, because of the order how EVM processes the constructor.

1. Storing child (`MainToken`) constructor arguments to memory (in your case no arguments)
2. Executing parent constructor.

   In your case the execution of `ERC777("MYTOKEN", "MTK", ops)` fails, because the **storage** variable `ops` is not available yet.
3. Executing child constructor (in your case `ops.push(msg.sender);`)

---

So the easiest Solution I could come up with, is passing the address from the `MyToken` argument. This is useful if you have control over the deployment process and can manually pass the value of `msg.sender` when you're deploying the contract.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC777/ERC777.sol';

contract MyToken is ERC777 {

    constructor(address[] memory defaultOperators)
        ERC777('MYTOKEN', 'MTK', defaultOperators) {
    }

}
```

---

If you're not going to have control over the deployment and need to assign `msg.sender` in constructor, I suggest copying the `ERC777` contract locally and modifying its constructor, so that it only adds the `msg.sender`.